# Почему не срабатывает столкновение текстур двух объектов?

Tags: java, libgdx

Здравствуйте! Имеется код для столкновения двух объектов и текстуры 16х16. Реализация такая, нужно что бы игрок прыгая на врага сверху убивал его, а по координате x враг убивал игрока...
С помощью класса Rectangle делаю проверку на столкновение затем внутри пишу такие условия.

Это условие для гибели игрока:

```
if((rectPlayer.x + rectPlayer.width < arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().x + arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().width 
|| rectPlayer.x + rectPlayer.width > arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().x + arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().width)
&& rectPlayer.y < arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().y + arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().height
.... тут какой либо код...
}
```

Это условие для удара игроком сверху по врагу:

```
if((rectPlayer.x + rectPlayer.width < arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().x + arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().width 
|| rectPlayer.x + rectPlayer.width > arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().x + arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().width)
&& rectPlayer.y > arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().y + arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().height
.... тут какой либо код...
}
```

Мой код по x координате работает... но стоит подключить этот то игрок его не может убить врага сверху... и игрок умирает почему то... либо наоборот, если убрать условие x то игрок прыгает на врага без проблем.... в чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Честно говоря, я никогда бы не понял по коду, что Вы хотите сделать. Вот моё предложение по реализации необходимых Вам экшенов:

```
if (rectPlayer.overlaps(arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect())) {
if (rectPlayer.y + rectPlayer.height > (arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().y + 
          arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().height)) {
    // Код для убийства существа
} else {
    // Код для убийства Player
}
```

}

Задумка такова, что идёт проверка на столкновение объектов, затем на сторону, откуда пришёл герой. Код не проверял, надеюсь, P.S.: В Вашем примере, скорее всего, спутаны координаты, а так же условия с ИЛИ следовало бы заключить в скобки.

Comment: спасибо за ответ... но ваш код не работает... скобочки лишние и -2 это лишнее... у меня идет сравнение точными размерами... буду думать дальше... спасибо, что ответили...

Comment: Попробуйте поколдовать над overlaps(), возможно, я забыл, как его правильно юзать, с libGDX давно не работал. Просто у меня был похожий проект, всё чётко работало.

Comment: я поменял ваш код... теперь он точно работает.. .спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinovich вы хотя бы комментарий для этого оставили бы при правке

Comment: @АлексейШиманский при правке и оставил комментарий в чем проблема то?

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinovich не было видно его при проверке. Поэтому странно выглядело.